# Problem to Connect Open Search dashboard and Get logs status

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, aws-api-gateway, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am trying to connect with open search dashboard and try to group all the logs hits on the basis of Internal team , exteranal team and client users . i wanted what filters should i use to discriminate among them . plus most importantly . How to get all data from open search dashboard directly through api gateway or any set up required ?

I want the method to do so